# Fixed the number of breakpoints used in Segmented R

Tags: r, linear-regression, piecewise

I am using the segmented function to fit my data with a piecewise linear regression.
As a first approach I didnt set any initial value for the breakpoints and number of them, and the algorithm got 10 breakpoints. Now I would like to fixed the number of breakpoints, i.e, going from 3 breakpoints to 10 breakpoints and check the error to take a fit which has the least number of breakpoints and performs a good fit. I though that the input npsi = n0 allows you to fixed the number of breakpoints, but I have set npsi = 3 and the output still 10 breakpoints.

```
seg6 <- segmented(LinearMod, seg.Z = ~x, psi = NA, npsi = 3)
```

Is there any method to do this?.

Comment: Try removing `psi = NA`, this is the first time I see your behavior and cannot reproduce it with fake data. Can you post the code you've tried and sample data? Please edit **the question** with the code you ran and the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`. (Note: `df` is the name of your dataset.)

Comment: Hi, I remove psi = NA and It works thanks a lot.